# Using PyTorch nn.Sequential() to define a network in a flexible way but with results beyond expectation

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I tried to define a network in a more flexible way using `nn.Sequential` so that I can define its number of layers according to `layernum`:

```py
seed = 0
torch.manual_seed(seed)
# ====== net_a =====
layers = [ nn.Linear(7, 64), nn.Tanh()]
for i in range(layernum-1): # layernum = 3
    layers.append(nn.Linear(64, 64))
    layers.append(nn.Tanh())
layers.append(nn.Linear(64, 8))
net_x = nn.Sequential(*layers)
net_y = nn.Sequential(*layers)
net_z = nn.Sequential(*layers)

# ====== net_b =====
net_x = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Linear(7, 64),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(64, 64),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(64, 64),
    nn.Tanh(),
    nn.Linear(64, 8),
)
net_y = nn.Sequential(
    #... same as net_x
)
net_z = nn.Sequential(
    #... same as net_x
)

# print(net_x)
# print(net_x[0].weight)
```

I use both of them **individually**, i.e. they are in the same .py file, but I use either of them and make the other as comments. Both of them consist of 3 networks with respect to 3 dimentions (x,y, and z).

I expected them to be the same network with same training performance.

The structure seems to be the same according to `print(net_x)`:

```py
    # Sequential(
    #   (0): Linear(in_features=7, out_features=64, bias=True)
    #   (1): Tanh()
    #   (2): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=64, bias=True)
    #   (3): Tanh()
    #   (4): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=64, bias=True)
    #   (5): Tanh()
    #   (6): Linear(in_features=64, out_features=8, bias=True)
    # )
```

But their initial weights are different according to `print(net_x[0].weight)`:

```py
print(net_x[0].weight) # net_a
    # tensor([[-0.0028,  0.2028, -0.3111, -0.2782, -0.1456,  0.1014, -0.0075],
    #         [ 0.2997, -0.0335,  0.1000, -0.1142, -0.0743, -0.3611, -0.2503],
    #         ......

print(net_x[0].weight) # net_b
    # tensor([[ 0.2813,  0.2968,  0.0078,  0.1518,  0.3776, -0.3247,  0.0071],
    #         [ 0.3448, -0.0988, -0.2798,  0.3347,  0.3581,  0.2229,  0.2841],
    #         ......
```

======**ADDED**=====

I trained the network like this:

```py
def train_on_batch(x, y, net, stepsize=innerstepsize):
    x = totorch(x)
    y = totorch(y)
    if(use_cuda):
        x,y = x.cuda(),y.cuda()
    net.zero_grad()
    ypred = net(x)
    loss = (ypred - y).pow(2).mean()
    loss.backward()
    for param in net.parameters():
        param.data -= stepsize * param.grad.data

iteration = 100
for iter in range(iteration):

    # TRAIN
    PrepareSample() # get in_support
    for i in range(tnum_support):
        out_x = trajectory_support_x[i,1:9]
        out_y = trajectory_support_y[i,1:9]
        out_z = trajectory_support_z[i,1:9]
        # Do SGD on this task
        for _ in range(innerepochs): # SGD 1 times
            train_on_batch(in_support[i], out_x, net_x)
            train_on_batch(in_support[i], out_y, net_y)
            train_on_batch(in_support[i], out_z, net_z)

    # TEST
    if iter==0 or (iter+1) % 10 == 0:
        ind = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
        loss = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
        for i in range(tnum_test):
            inputs = in_test[i]
            outputs_x = trajectory_test_x[i].tolist()
            x_test = trajectory_test_x[i,[0,9]]
            y_test = trajectory_test_x[i,1:9]
            pred_x = np.hstack((x_test[0],predict(inputs, net_x),x_test[1]))
            loss[i] = np.square(predict(inputs, net_x) - y_test).mean() # mse

            inputs = in_test[i]
            outputs_y = trajectory_test_y[i].tolist()
            x_test = trajectory_test_y[i,[0,9]]
            y_test = trajectory_test_y[i,1:9]
            pred_y = np.hstack((x_test[0],predict(inputs, net_y),x_test[1]))
            loss[i+2] = np.square(predict(inputs, net_y) - y_test).mean() # mse

            inputs = in_test[i]
            outputs_z = trajectory_test_z[i].tolist()
            x_test = trajectory_test_z[i,[0,9]]
            y_test = trajectory_test_z[i,1:9]
            pred_z = np.hstack((x_test[0],predict(inputs, net_z),x_test[1]))
            loss[i+4] = np.square(predict(inputs, net_z) - y_test).mean() # mse

        iterNum.append(iter+1)
        avgloss.append(np.mean(loss))
```

both of them are trained with **exactly the same data** (they are in the same .py file and of course use the same data).

=====**This is avgloss of net_a**:
[image]

=====**This is avgloss of net_a with `torch.manual_seed(seed)` before every network definition**:
[image]

=====**This is avgloss of net_b**:
[image]

=====**This is avgloss of net_b with `torch.manual_seed(seed)` before every network definition**:
[image]
The training of `net_a` is weird, the MSE is high at initial time, and didn't reduce. On the contrary, the training of `net_b` seems common, the MSE is relatively low at first, and reduce to a smaller value after 100 iterations.

Is anyone know how to fix this?  I would like to go through different layer number, layer size, activation functions of the network. I don't want to write every network of specified hyper-parameters.

Comment: `their initial weights are different [...] immediately after their definition` that's because `nn.Linear` weights are [randomly initialized](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/e44b2b72bd4ccecf9c2f6c18d09c11eff446b5a3/torch/nn/modules/linear.py#L55). As for the losses being so different, they shouldn't if those two versions are training with the exact same data/hyper-parameters. Can you provide the code you used to train them?

Comment: @Ivan thank you for your comment. I've updated my question to include the training codes and the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The random state is different after `torch` initialized the weights in the first network. You need to reset the random state to keep the same initialization by calling `torch.manual_seed(seed)` after the definition of the first network and before the second one.
2. The problem lies in `net_x/y/z` -- it will be perfectly fine if it were just `net_x`. When you use `nn.Sequential`, it does not create new modules but instead stores a reference to the given module. So, in your first definition, you only have **one** copy of the layers, meaning that all `net_x/y/z` are shared-weight. They have independent weights in your second definition, which is naturally what we are after.

You might definite it like this instead:

```py
def get_net():
    layers = [ nn.Linear(7, 64), nn.Tanh()]
    for i in range(layernum-1): # layernum = 3
        layers.append(nn.Linear(64, 64))
        layers.append(nn.Tanh())
    layers.append(nn.Linear(64, 8))
    return layers

net_x = nn.Sequential(*get_net())
net_y = nn.Sequential(*get_net())
net_z = nn.Sequential(*get_net())
```

Each time `get_net` is called, it creates a new copy.

Comment: (2) No need for that, OP defined `net_b` as `nn.Sequential(*layers)`

Comment: @Ivan then idk, we need to see the training code.

Comment: @hkchengrex thank you for your comment. I've updated my question with training codes and results.

Comment: @hkchengrex Thanks! It works. According to (1), does it mean I have to call `torch.manual_seed(seed)` after the definition of each network? The result is already reproducible, but slightly different whether or not I call it before definition (see figures of `avgloss` of net_b). I don't know which one is more stable or 'formal'.

Comment: @abmin In general, it is a good idea to set a global seed at the beginning but you don't have to do it for every network. We only do that when we want to make sure two things are equivalent.